# How to rename column with certain words in it

Tags: python, pandas, rename

Noob in python here. Forgive me if I'm asking stupid questions (which I hope I'm not).

I have a dataframe 1 that look like this:

```
Running rate ($/hour)        Eating rate (lb/hour)     Age
50                          20                         50 
30                          10                         40
```

and another dataframe 2 that look like this:

```
Running rate (km/hour)     Eating rate (kg/hour)      Age
5                          23                         50 
3                          18                         40
```

Now I want to:

1. Loop through all the dataframes (which i have achieved so)

   2. replace all the "(XX/hour)" to 'per hour'.

So basically, regardless whether it's "lb/hour" or "km/hour" or "kg/hour", I want them to be changed to "per hour", so the two dataframes should look like the following:

dataframe 1 desired output:

```
Running rate per hour       Eating rate per hour       Age
50                          20                         50 
30                          10                         40
```

dataframe 2 desired output:

```
Running rate per hour      Eating rate per hour       Age
5                          23                         50 
3                          18                         40
```

I've looked into many posts and tried using

```
> df.rename(columns={'a':'b'})
```

, but this method only changes column named 'a' to name 'b', and I don't know how to incorporate the Regex version into it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can get all the column names with `df.columns`.  You can then loop through all the names and modify them.  You might try the `split` method to split on the `/`, and keep only the first term.  After you have new versions of all the columns, you can use df.rename(dict(zip(columns, newColumns)), inplace=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.columns = [re.sub('\(.+/(.+)\)', r'per \1', c) for c in df.columns]
```

Here `df` is a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), and `re` is the [regular expression module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

---

**Update:** Clarification on the [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) used.

I actually did a more general form than needed here. The simplest regex for the OP would actually be

```
[re.sub('\(.+/hour\)', 'per hour', c) for c in ['A (a/hour)', 'B (b/hour)', 'Age']]
```

The regex I used was to allow for a general denominator. For example, the simpler regex

```
[re.sub('\(.+/hour\)', 'per hour', c) for c in ['A (a/hour)', 'B (b/day)', 'Age']]
```

gives

```
['A per hour', 'B (b/day)', 'Age']
```

But the more general regex

```
[re.sub('\(.+/(.+)\)', r'per \1', c) for c in ['A (a/hour)', 'B (b/day)', 'Age']]
```

gives

```
['A per hour', 'B per day', 'Age']
```

The change from `hour` to `(.+)` in the pattern [*captures*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) an arbitrary word, rather than just recognizing `hour`. The change from `per hour` to `per \1` in the substitution puts that captured word (group 1 in the pattern), rather than just `hour`. (The [`r`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) prefacing the string just means the `\` is interpreted literally, rather than as an escape.)

Comment: hi thank you! can you be a bit more specific on what '\(.+/(.+)\)' is doing? and why use 'per \1'?

Comment: I misread, and so made a more general regex: It takes "(a/b)" to "per b". The ".+" recognizes a word of 1 or more characters (until the "/" for a, or the ")" for b). The first one (a) is discarded, and the second (b) is captured as group 1, then put back in after the "per".

Comment: doesnt work :( the error keeps occuring: TypeError: Could not compare ['\\(.+/(.+)\\)'] with block values

Comment: So it will work also for "per day" or "per mile" or whatever denominator. Symbols are not a problem.

Comment: I tried it, it doesnt work :(  what could be the problem?

Comment: no i did not put the brackets. they added the brackets in the error code. here's the code in my script that i used based on your answer: PriceDataAll.columns.values = [PriceDataAll.sub('\(.+/(.+)\)', r'per \1', s) for s in PriceDataAll.columns.values]

Comment: There is no `.values`, just `columns`.

Comment: And `re.sub()`. This is a different module (see updated answer): `re.sub()` is not the same as `pandas.DataFrame.sub()`. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: ah thank you so much! that was the issue :) it works now!  but can  you please explain in your answer what the 'per \1' is for? i am still a bit confused about that. thank you so much!